# python regex return non-capturing group

Tags: python, regex

I want to generate a username from an email with :

- firstname's first letter
- lastname's first 7 letters

eg :

```
getUsername("my-firstname.my-lastname@email.com")
mmylastn
```

Here is `getUsername`'s code :

```py
def getUsername(email) :
   re.match(r"(.){1}[a-z]+.([a-z]{7})",email.replace('-','')).group()
```

- `email.replace('-','')` to get rid of the `-` symbol
- regex that captures the 2 groups I discribed above

If I do `.group(1,2)` I can see the captured groups are `m` and `mylastn`, so it's all good.
But using `.group()` doesn't just return the capturing group but also everthing between them : `myfirstnamemlastn`

Can someone explain me this behavior ?

Comment: First, escape the `.` if you want to match a literal dot. Also, `{1}` is redundant, remove it. Next, if you need to get a `mmylastn` string, just join the groups, `"".join(re.match(...).groups())` - see https://rextester.com/UMOO62524

Comment: I think you can achieve this simply without even using regex.
`firstName, lastName = email.split('@')[0].replace('-','').split('.')`
`print(firstName[0] + lastName[0:7])`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew omg you are reactiv ! Thanks a lot, it works ;)

Comment: I posted the solution with comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a `.` in a pattern is a metacharacter that matches any char excluding line break chars. You need to escape the `.` in the regex pattern

Also, `{1}` limiting quantifier is always redundant, you may safely remove it from any regex you have.

Next, if you need to get a `mmylastn` string as a result, you cannot use `match.group()` because `.group()` fetches the *overall match value*, not the concatenated capturing group values.

So, in your case,

- Check if there is a match first, trying to access `None.groups()` will throw an exception
- Then join the `match.groups()`

You can use

```py
import re
def getUsername(email) :
    m = re.match(r"(.)[a-z]+\.([a-z]{7})",email.replace('-',''))
    if m:
        return "".join(m.groups())
    return email

print(getUsername("my-firstname.my-lastname@email.com"))
```

See the Python demo.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why {1} is always redundant? I don't understand why `(.)[a-z]+` return the 1st char' rather than the whole first word

Comment: @Will `.` = `.{1}` = match any one char other than line break chars, matching a pattern once is the default behavior. `n` matches a single `n`, and `n{1}` matches an `n` once. That is why.